# how to get full outer join in left and right join order

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Please refer the below script

```
    declare @table1 table
    (
    col1 int
    )

    declare @table2 table
    (
    col2 int
    )

    insert into @table1 values(1)
    insert into @table1 values(2)
    insert into @table1 values(3)
    insert into @table1 values(5)
    insert into @table1 values(7)

    insert into @table2 values(1)
    insert into @table2 values(3)
    insert into @table2 values(3)
    insert into @table2 values(6)
    insert into @table2 values(4)
    insert into @table2 values(7)
```

Case 1:

```
select * from @table1 a left outer join @table2 b on a.col1=b.col2
    order by col1
```

Result 1:

```
         col1       col2        
     -----------  ----------- 
    |    1       |    1       |
    |    2       |    NULL    |
    |    3       |    3       |
    |    3       |    3       |
    |    5       |    NULL    |
    |    7       |    7       |
    ---------------------------
```

Case 2:

```
select * from @table1 a right outer join @table2 b on a.col1=b.col2
    order by col2
```

Result 2:

```
         col1             col2        
     -----------  ----------- 
    |    1       |    1       |
    |    3       |    3       |
    |    3       |    3       |
    |    NULL    |    4       |
    |    NULL    |    6       |
    |    7       |    7       |
    ---------------------------
```

Actual Case:

```
select * from @table1 a full outer join @table2 b on a.col1=b.col2
```

Actual Result:

```
         col1        col2        
     -----------  ----------- 
    |    1       |    1       |
    |    2       |    NULL    |
    |    3       |    3       |
    |    3       |    3       |
    |    5       |    NULL    |
    |    7       |    7       |
    |    NULL    |    6       |
    |    NULL    |    4       |
    ---------------------------
```

Expected Result:

```
         col1        col2        
     -----------  ----------- 
    |    1       |    1       |
    |    2       |    NULL    |
    |    3       |    3       |
    |    3       |    3       |
    |    NULL    |    4       |
    |    5       |    NULL    |
    |    NULL    |    6       |
    |    7       |    7       |
    ---------------------------
```

I tried union all with left and right join query but it doubles the result set. Is there a way that I can get this expected output.

Thanks,
Esen.

Comment: Why would you expect any particular order without having an `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: that is my question. I don't know how to order by in this case. Luckly @Martin answered to my question which resolved my issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT *
FROM   @table1 a
       FULL OUTER JOIN @table2 b
         ON a.col1 = b.col2
ORDER  BY Isnull(col1, col2)
```

to get your desired order. Without an `ORDER BY` no ordering is guaranteed.